# Does stimulating the hypothalamus signal brain to store less body fat?

Tags: neurology, weight-loss

I come across another [Indiegogo project](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/modius-groundbreaking-fat-reduction-technology-fitness-health#/) that promises a weight loss just by carrying their device on the head. This device stimulates nerves behind the ear. They claim that these nerves send a signal to the hypothalamus, part of the brain that controls how the body store body fat.

I'm very skeptical and in shock that the project already got so much funding. They don't show any people who were on the trail and didn't show any results except the founder showing his stomach. I feel like this is another scam, I'm just surprised how many people already pre-ordered something so ridiculous. It reminds me [Ritot](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ritot-the-first-projection-watch). How much of the claim is true? Can their clinical trials be found somewhere? They said they spent 5 years researching, it must be well documented.

[image]

Comment: It's tackling the symptoms rather than the causes, but the hypothalamus is indeed [involved in regulating insulin](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3282803/) so the idea at least has some theoretical merit. That said, the hypothalamus is also involved in a whole bunch of other things in the brain and out of it, so IMHO it's rather speculative for it to have no side effects.